# How to draw Arrow in angular 4?

Tags: angular

Please give me some idea. How to draw arrow on canvas in angular 4 ?
using with fabric.js library.
I am trying with this but triangle is not rotate.
this is write in angular8 but in this code one problem. traiangle in not rotate according to direction of arrow.
Please give me some idea. How to draw arrow on canvas in angular 4 ?
using with fabric.js library.
I am trying with this but triangle is not rotate.
this is write in angular8 but in this code one problem. traiangle in not rotate according to direction of arrow.
Please give me some idea. How to draw arrow on canvas in angular 4 ?
using with fabric.js library.
I am trying with this but triangle is not rotate.
this is write in angular8 but in this code one problem. traiangle in not rotate according to direction of arrow.

```
this.canvas.on("mouse:down", (eve) => {

        var pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(eve.e);
        var linePositionX = pointer.x;
        var linePositionY = pointer.y;
        this.triangle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 2,


            left: linePositionX,
            top: linePositionY,

            originX: "center",
            originY: "center",

        });

        this.exitCirclePoint = new fabric.Triangle({

            width: 20,
            height: 10,

            stroke: 'orange',
            strokeWidth: 2,


            fill: "orange",
            left: linePositionX,
            top: linePositionY,

            originX: "center",
            originY: "center",

        });

        this.canvas.add(this.exitCirclePoint);

        this.exitCirclePointsArray.push(this.exitCirclePoint);

        if (
            this.exitCirclePointsArray.length > 1 &&
            this.exitCirclePointsArray.length < 3
        ) {
            var startPoint = this.exitCirclePointsArray[
                this.exitCirclePointsArray.length - 2
            ];
            var endPoint = this.exitCirclePointsArray[
                this.exitCirclePointsArray.length - 1
            ];

            var exitWaterLine = new fabric.Line(
                [
                    startPoint.get("left"),
                    startPoint.get("top"),
                    endPoint.get("left"),
                    endPoint.get("top"),
                ], {
                    stroke: "orange",
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    hasControls: false,
                    hasBorders: false,


                    hoverCursor: "default",
                    originX: "center",
                    originY: "center",
                }
            );

            this.exitCircleLineArray.push(exitWaterLine);

            this.canvas.add(exitWaterLine);


        }
        if (this.exitCirclePointsArray.length == 1) {
            this.canvas.remove(this.exitCirclePoint);
            this.canvas.add(this.triangle);
        }
        if (this.exitCirclePointsArray.length > 2) {
            this.canvas.remove(this.exitCirclePoint);
            this.canvas.remove(exitWaterLine);
            this.exitCircleLineArray.length = 0;


        });

    this.canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: in this link make it with only css: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/